# My button click is working only the first time

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a classic ASP NET page on my SharePoint site with several buttons in it:

> ```
>             Button importZIPPOTBtn = new Button();
>             importZIPPOTBtn.Click += new EventHandler(importZIPPOTBtn_Click);
>             this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/><br/>"));
>             this.Controls.Add(importZIPPOTBtn);
> ```

The first click on any button is perfectly firing the event, but any further click on any button doesn't fire, I can't understand why...

Comment: button controls must be placed inside form tag of asp.net page.

Answer (score 0):

Consider aadding button to form1 or container element like panel inside page.

```
Button importZIPPOTBtn = new Button();
importZIPPOTBtn.Click += new EventHandler(importZIPPOTBtn_Click);
this.form1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/><br/>"));
this.form1.Controls.Add(importZIPPOTBtn);
```

You can verfiy in html source, unless you add this way even literal control containing lines breaks will not be rendered.